# Elasticsearch 1.5 Won't Add _timestamp

Tags: elasticsearch, timestamp, mapping

I am using this request when creating my index:

```
PUT some_name
{
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "_timestamp" : {
        "enabled": true,
        "store": true
      },
      "properties": {
        "properties": {
          "properties": {
            "location": {
              "type": "geo_point"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, _timestamp field is not being returned, basically when I add a document (without any time field) and request it back. I am running Elasticsearch 1.5, and I have tried `"store": "yes"`, `"store": "true"`.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specifically ask for that field to be returned: `"fields": ["_timestamp"]` because it's a field that's not commonly returned and is not included in the `_source` (the default being returned):

```
GET /some_name/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "fields": ["_timestamp"]
}
```